# Codeigniter cannot refresh page after session destroy and direct

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have a PHP program written on code igniter that needs your help! Have been trying for 3 weeks!

I have the htaccess mod rewrite to make http://www.sampleurl.com/controllername instead of http://www.sampleurl.com/index.php/controllername

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I have a controller for Dashboard (currently used for testing the session.)

```
public function index()
    {
            $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('fb_session');

            $data = array(
                'fb_data' => $is_logged_in,
            );

            if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true){
                redirect('/error');
            }


        }
```

Below is the function that suppose to kill the current session and redirect to dashboard page.

```
$('#logoutbtn').click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "/fbcontroller/killsession",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(){
                alert("Logout");
            }
         });
    });


 public function killsession(){
           $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('/dashboard');
        }
```

Problem 1: as I redirect from function in 1 controller to another, the redirection fails here. Instead of directing to dashboard, the firebug displays 404 error, page not found. And in the response, it displays all the HTML code of /error page. Does it mean that the redirection works? If yes, why wouldn't it display on browser?

Problem 2: session destroyed, but logged in page stays even as I refresh (F5).

Comment: I suspect its the htaccess that is causing all these problem.

Comment: For your information,  session_destroy(); solved the issue by destroying the session and when I do F5 refresh, it logs user out. However, it is strange that session is there after redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For htaccess I suggest:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And know that when you kill session CI will create a new 1 on your next Page load (in your case on the redirect) .. Session isn't just for user logins.

Don't forget at app/config/config.php to set

```
$config["index_page"] = '';
```

Comment: Hi Svetlio, it does not solve the issue of POST ../index.php/fbcontroller/killsession
404 Not Found
650ms 
 in the console. Please enlighten me with your answer. :)

Comment: where is that killsession action  ? at FB controller ?

Comment: Yes, it kills the session created from a class.

Comment: If you have set correct httaccess, you need to set at config.php the index_page to be empty.  at the moment index.php/ shouldn't shows up at your urls :)

Comment: I changed the ajax URL as per your command but I am still getting the same console error. What am I missing? Sorry to bother you too much! :(

Comment: Just try to open localhost/fbcontroller/killsession at browser.. if it gives you 404 your htaccess doesn't work else if it works you don't have problem (at javascript write url with slash at start "/fbcontroller/killsession"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39336/discussion-between-bryan-wong-and-svetlio)