# CodeIgniter 3 sessions destroy after page refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, xampp

Despite the countless similar questions here, non of them works in my case. So, I decided to post it here.

Well the problem is that the session is being destroy after page refresh/redirect.

I'm using the XAMPP server(latest version with PHP 7.x) on Windows 10, I think, its the problem with codeigniter settings but, I just test the traditional session code (without Codeigniter) and that works fine.

**Traditional PHP Code (Works Fine)**

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    $_SESSION['admin']='test';
    die('session not set, set it now');
}
else {
    echo $_SESSION['admin'];
}
```

**Codeigniter Code (Here is the Problem)**

```
if($this->session->userdata('admin')) {
    echo $this->session->userdata('admin');
}
else {
    $this->session->set_userdata('admin', 'test');
    echo 'session not set, set it now';
}
```

**Codeigniter Session Config**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\application\\cache\\session\\';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

**NOTE** The Same Codeigniter code works fine on WAMP Server - Windows 10

Comment: Just a tip rather than write like `$config['sess_save_path'] = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\application\\cache\\session\\';`  use `APPPATH` like `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH .  'cache/session/';`

Comment: I honer your suggestion, Although, I've manually checked the directory `C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\application\\cache\\session\\` and found session files there, means, it works fine.

Comment: so when do `print_r($this->session->userdata);` you are getting anything?

Comment: Only `Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1497678913 )`

Comment: `$_SESSION` this also returns same?

Comment: Yes, `$_SESSION` returns same.

Comment: Maybe this can help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398871/codeigniter-cannot-refresh-page-after-session-destroy-and-direct)

Comment: Just to be clear... the session is being destroyed once you simply reload the page?

Comment: @JasonBassett Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.I think you can have a look [Native-session](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session).This may solve your issue.

And also check `config.php` for `cookie_domain`.This should not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

The Session Settings seems correct, I like to suggest you, Please check the session library in Application/Config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Hope so this will help you

Comment: I don't understand, why you will get an error, if you will load session library, I think this is the right way